# How to empty the strings in an array of strings, but keep the length of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings in javaScript:

```
array = ['xx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxx'];
```

I want to reach this:

```
 array = ['', '', '']; //empty the strings but keep the length of array
```

What is the best way?

Comment: `array.map(() => '')` simple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

```js
array = ['xx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxx'];
array.fill('');
console.log(array)
```

If you need to create a new array, use the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor combined with `Array.fill`:

```js
array = ['xx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxx'];
const newArray = new Array(array.length);
newArray.fill('');
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

use .map method to remove content and return the empty string.

```js
array = ['xx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxx'];
const newArray = array.map(data=> (""));
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = array.map(function(item){return '';});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map()` method for immutability of original array.

```js
let array = ['xx', 'xxxxxxxx', 'xxx'];

const emptyArr = array.map((item)=>"");

console.log(emptyArr);
```